# ParseUser.setEmail() does not work with "some kind of Strings"?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, parse-platform

I'm trying to set the email in a user obtained from Facebook SDK. If I set the email with any string like this:

```
user.setEmail("whatever@whwhwh.com"); 
user.saveInBackground();
```

It works, no problem... it appears in Parse's Data Browser...

If I try to do what I need to do(see code below), then it doesn't work, I've checked the String value and it's ok, it is the needed email....I've tried different things.. no luck.. Please help, thanks.

```
user.setEmail(user.getProperty("email").toString());
user.saveInBackground();
```

Comment: please define "doesn't work". If there's an error post the stack trace. What is the output of `user.getProperty("email").toString()`?

Comment: The output is the desired email(as checked with Log). doesn't work= It doesn't save the email to parse user, nothing in Parse's Data Browser.  If I change it to a String like "xxxx@ccc.vom" it works, and gets saved to the Parse's Data Browser...   It is such a mistery.... Other expressions I've tried: response.getGraphObject().getProperty("email").toString();(String)userg.asMap().get("email");

Comment: Have you checked to see that the email is not being used by another user? Emails must be unique. Note that calling `saveInBackground` will actually not throw any exception if one does occur. Try adding the `SaveCallback` with `saveInBackground` like [here](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/SaveCallback.html) to see if an error is indeed being thrown.

Comment: Oh boy!! thanks, yes, my normal user has the same email....  I'll check and come back to tell you the results...

Comment: Thanks @singularhum , after 1 day trying stuff, you got it right!

Comment: No problem! Did you want me to add as an answer?

Comment: Sure, I'll put the vote... or something.. I'm not stack expert..  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the email being supplied is not used by any other user. This is because an email must be *[unique](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseException.html#EMAIL_TAKEN)*.

When calling `saveInBackground`, it will actually not throw any exception if one does occur. So in your case, if the email is a duplicate, the email won't get saved and no exception is thrown.

To catch an exception with `saveInBackground`, you can use the [SaveCallback](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/SaveCallback.html).

```
user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
  public void done(ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // No exception
    } else {
      // Exception occured
    }
  }
});
```

For a list of exceptions you can refer to [ParseException](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseException.html).